# jquery only allow one div element to be selected at a time on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have styled some markup where the user can select a DIV and it shows highlighted.. this works fine, however, I want to only allow one DIV to be highlighted and selected at time.. currently the user can select all 3 DIVS and they will all show highlighted.  I use jquery toggleClass to add/remove "active" class to DIV.  "active" class is styled in css to show blue background.

how can I stop users from selecting all 3?

```js
$('.pricecard.aircraft').click(function() {
  // this will fire when you click view
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price1">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price2">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price3">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: radio buttons FTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal call `removeClass()` on all the other `.pricecard.aircraft` elements which are not the one which was clicked on:

```js
let $divs = $('.pricecard.aircraft').click(function() {
  $divs.not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price1">£20,944</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price2">£20,944</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price3">£20,944</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Rory, How do I copy the selected DIV to the DIV section below it.. ie, there's a another copy of the 3 DIVS with a different class below and I want to copy whats selected to the below DIVs?

Comment: `clone()` and `append()` should be able to handle that, but it depends on your exact HTML. I'd suggest starting a new question about it, including all the relevant containers.

Answer (score 2):

Just using HTML and CSS, no JavaScript is needed.

```css
[name="price"]:checked + label > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="radio" name="price" id="price1" value="20944" class="d-none"/>
<label class="col-sm-4 my-1 d-inline-block" for="price1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price1">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" id="price2" value="20944" class="d-none"/>
<label class="col-sm-4 my-1 d-inline-block" for="price2">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price2">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="price" id="price3" value="20944" class="d-none"/>
<label class="col-sm-4 my-1 d-inline-block" for="price3">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price3">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
$('.pricecard.aircraft').click(function() {
  $('.pricecard.aircraft').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.pricecard.aircraft.active {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft active h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price1">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price2">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 my-1">
  <div class="card pricecard aircraft h-100">
    <div class="card-body">
      <span class="price3">£20,944</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works!